# Problem while lunching CS2 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, steam

I have an issue with Steam, while I launch [CS2](https://store.steampowered.com/app/730), it suddenly stops processing, my PC is compatible with the game and I don't know the reason why it happens. If anyone knows the answer please let me know.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Whenever you're trying to get a game to work through Steamplay, it's worth checking ProtonDB for that game and see what other people's experiences are and if they have any advice. [Here's the page for CS2](https://www.protondb.com/app/730)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try to fix the issue of CS2 stopping processing when you launch it on Steam:

Verify the integrity of the game cache. This will check all of the game files to make sure that they are not corrupted. To do this, right-click on CS2 in your Steam library and select "Properties". Then, click on the "Local Files" tab and select "Verify integrity of game files...".
Update your graphics drivers. Outdated or corrupted graphics drivers can cause all sorts of problems with games. To update your graphics drivers, visit the website of your graphics card manufacturer and download the latest drivers.
Update your operating system. Make sure that you are running the latest version of your operating system. To check for updates, go to your operating system's settings menu and look for an "Updates" section.
Try running the game as an administrator. This can sometimes fix problems with games that are caused by permissions issues. To do this, right-click on the CS2 executable file and select "Run as administrator".
Try running the game in compatibility mode. This can sometimes fix problems with games that are caused by compatibility issues with your operating system. To do this, right-click on the CS2 executable file and select "Properties". Then, click on the "Compatibility" tab and select "Run this program in compatibility mode for:" and select your operating system from the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using nouveau driver

Installing the nvidia 525 driver helped me, rtx 2060 in my case

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525
```

and restart system and check

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
```

you will see like

```
administrator@administrator:~$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_uvm           1593344  0
nvidia_drm             86016  6
nvidia_modeset       1253376  8 nvidia_drm
nvidia              56389632  379 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        249856  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   696320  10 drm_kms_helper,nvidia,nvidia_drm
i2c_nvidia_gpu         16384  0
i2c_ccgx_ucsi          16384  1 i2c_nvidia_gpu
video                  69632  2 asus_wmi,nvidia_modeset

administrator@administrator:~$ lsmod | grep nouveau
administrator@administrator:~$
```